# How can I add css class to menu_tree_output in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to print menu in D7 and everything is working fine for me, except the menu is displaying the predefined class i.e.(menu).

The code snippet I am trying is:

```
<?php
$menuTree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-top-menu');
$menu_tree_array = menu_tree_output($menuTree);
print render($menu_tree_array);
?>
```

The above code results:

```
<ul class="menu"><li class="menu__item is-leaf first leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/beyond-business">Beyond Business</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/career">Career</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/media">Media</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-expanded last expanded"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/the-group">The Group</a><ul class="menu"><li class="menu__item is-leaf first last leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/chairmans-message">Chairman's Message</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

I want an output like the below one, i.e. I want to add 3 classes (nav navbar-nav top-nav)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav"><li class="menu__item is-leaf first leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/beyond-business">Beyond Business</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/career">Career</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/media">Media</a></li>
<li class="menu__item is-expanded last expanded"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/the-group">The Group</a><ul class="menu"><li class="menu__item is-leaf first last leaf"><a class="menu__link" title="" href="/guptapower.com/cms/chairmans-message">Chairman's Message</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I never use 'menu_tree_output' to output menu but u now ander method can help you

```
$title = t('My List');
$type = 'ul';
$attributes = array(
'id' => 'my-list',
'class' => 'nav navbar-nav top-nav',
);
$items = array(
'0' => array(
'data' => 'Item 1',
'id' => 'item_1',
'class' => array('item-1')
),
'1' => array(
'data' => 'Item 2',
'id' => 'item_2',
'class' => array('item-2'),
'children' => array(
  '0' => array(
    'data' => 'Sub Item 1',
    'id' => 'sub_1',
    'class' => array('sub-item-1')
  ),
  '1' => array(
    'data' => 'Sub Item 2',
    'id' => 'sub_2',
    'class' => array('sub-item-2')
  ),
),
),
'2' => array(
'data' => 'Item 3',
'id' => 'item_3',
'class' => array('item-3')
),
);

return theme_item_list(array(
'items' => $items,
'title' => $title,
'type' => $type,
'attributes' => $attributes
));
```

The Output will look like this:

```
<div class="item-list">
<h3>My List</h3>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav" id="my-list">
<li class="item-1 first" id="item_1">Item 1</li>
<li class="item-2" id="item_2">Item 2
  <div class="item-list">
    <ul class="item-2" id="item_2">
      <li class="sub-item-1 first" id="sub_1">SubItem 1</li>
      <li class="sub-item-2 last" id="sub_2">SubItem 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item-3 last" id="item_3">Item 3</li>
```

i wish this code help you